# Is it possible to have conditional content field in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

### How to add a conditional field in Strapi?

**I want to have a conditional field, which will only appear if the boolean field is true**

**For example**;

Dog content type has a Boolean field (asking if the dog has a beard), 
if it does then It asks for the color of it.

```js
viewColorField = (beardStatus == TRUE)? TRUE : FALSE;
```

[image: condional fields]

Is it possible in **Strapi admin area** or should I solve it frontend?

I am using Strapi v3.0.0-beta.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option doesn't exist by default in Strapi.

If you want your can try to customize the admin panel to match your need.

To do that you will have to read and understand some concept / code base of Strapi.

- Customization - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html

This will let you update the admin panel of a plugin, in your case, the content manager plugin.

- Content Manager admin code - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/strapi-plugin-content-manager/admin/src

I suggest you to check this source code, find where the **Edit View** container is managed.

Then customize it to add a condition for your specific Content Type and Field.

This will be a little bit tricky but it's possible to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to show some fields based on the push notification type, (Broadcast, topics, specific user/users) so I used the **dynamic zones with components** and got something like this :
[image]